# ASP.MVC Ajax response returns form with some JS not executing

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

ASP.NET MVC Page has one link (Ajax.ActionLink), which gets the form to create and puts it in one of the div. I see the form in div but none of the JavaScript returned is getting executed. I am using JQuery validation and needs to run the validate() on the form so that returned form from AJAX request is validated.

Is there any setting or trick I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Please post example code.  Specifically, what kind of data are you returning back (JSON, text, etc.) and how are you taking this information in on the client-side?

Comment: <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Create", "Create", null,
    new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divCreate", HttpMethod = "GET", OnComplete = "openCreateNew" }, new { id = "create" })%>

<div id="divCreate">
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 ways I have it working now.

1. User the JQuery $.get and replace the html returned into the div. This is now executing the script for me.
2. Other option is remove the UpdateTargetId and ReplaceMode from the AjaxOptions and use call back to replace the html into div tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, just replace the Sys.Mvc.MvcHelpers.updateDomElement with your own implementation.

```
(function ($) {
    if (Sys && Sys.Mvc && Sys.Mvc.MvcHelpers) {

        Sys.Mvc.MvcHelpers.updateDomElement = function My$updateDomElement(target, insertionMode, content) {
            /// <param name="target" type="Object" domElement="true">
            /// </param>
            /// <param name="insertionMode" type="Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode">
            /// </param>
            /// <param name="content" type="String">
            /// </param>
            if (target) {
                var $target = $(target);
                switch (insertionMode) {
                    case Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace:
                        $target.html(content);
                        break;
                    case Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.insertBefore:
                        if (content && content.length > 0) {
                           $target.prepend(content);
                        }
                        break;
                    case Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.insertAfter:
                        if (content && content.length > 0) {
                            $target.append(content);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Since jQuery handles script tags correctly, that should fix your problem.